# Any way to run UI thread briefly when non-UI thread is stopped in debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

When debugging background threads using Visual Studio 2010, is there any nice way to let other threads run for a few hundred milliseconds or so without advancing a thread that's sitting at a breakpoint?  Equivalent in effect to inserting "Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)" just before the current line, setting next statement there, and hitting resume (but without hacking the code being debugged)?  My packet-logging/display code isn't as useful as it could be, since the debugger will often hit a breakpoint between the time my code has acted on a packet, and the time the UI has managed to display it.

I know it's possible to go into the Threads window, Freeze the thread that hit the breakpoint, hit run, hit pause, and thaw the thread that hit the breakpoint, but that's really clunky.  Is there a smoother way to do things?

(Edit)Why no response I wonder?  I can't believe I'm the only person trying to debug non-UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a **Macro** within Visual Studio to complete actions such the one you outline.

It should be a simple matter of recording the Macro (`Tools`, `Macros`, `Record TemporaryMacro`) at the right point in time and then saving it.

You can always add a Icon / keyboard shortcut to run the macro again at a later time.

Or even tweak the source code to the macro to ensure it does your action exactly as needed.

**EDIT #1:** As a hint I would imagine the code looks a little like this (not tested):

```
    Dim t As Thread
    t = DTE.Debugger.CurrentThread
    t.Freeze()
    DTE.Debugger.Go(False)
    Beep()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    Beep()
    DTE.Debugger.Break(True)
    DTE.Debugger.CurrentThread = t;
    t.Thaw()
```

**EDIT #2:**
You might want to refer to this: [EnvDTE.Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.debugger.aspx)

Standard imports for your reference:

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics
```

Comment: How should I have the macro work?  It would have to freeze the current thread and run other threads for a certain length of time, then unfreeze the current thread.  If I'm doing things manually, I can see which thread is the current thread and just freeze that one, but I'm unaware of any "freeze current thread" command, nor am I aware of any command that would cause a macro to wait while the other threads ran for a certain amount of time.

Comment: On Monday, I'll test out freezing/unfreezing threads while a macro recording is in progress to see what gets recorded, but I'm not sure what commands I could record that would achieve the desired result independent of which threads get assigned what ids.  BTW, if I've tried doing "Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)" in the immediate window, but all threads are frozen when that's running.  Thanks for your assistance--I'll let you know on Monday what happens.

Comment: @Dean Taylor: Thanks.  I don't think I'd have figured that out on my own; what's DTE?  Is there someplace I can look for more information about it?

Comment: @supercat Added list of standard imports for a Visual Studio  macro and reference to MSDN documentation for Debugger interface.

Comment: @Dean Taylor: Wow, that looks awesome.  I'll let you know on Monday how it works out.

Comment: @Dean Taylor: Thanks a million.  It works awesome.  The automation stuff for VS2010 looks huge; any advice for how best to search the documentation?  The next thing I'd like to do would be to import color settings when a project is created or loaded, based on the name of the project, so that different projects would have different color settings.  Unfortunately, macro recording only yields DTE.ExecuteCommand("Tools.ImportandExportSettings"), which pops up the load-config window rather than just loading a config.

Comment: @Dean Taylor: The documentation is confusing, but I found what I was looking for: CType(DTE.Properties("FontsAndColors", "TextEditor").Item("FontsAndColorsItems").Object, EnvDTE.FontsAndColorsItems).Item("Plain Text").Background = 255 works great to change a color setting.

Comment: @supercat Glad you found what you are after, usually Google "`MSDN DTE What ever you are after`" is the simplest way to search for things.